# Scrapy + Playwright error: "node:events:505 throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event"

Tags: python, scrapy, playwright

I'm doing scrapping with scrapy + playwright of an ecommerce website, approximately in one hour returns 42k registers and broken with the message:

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (node:internal/stream_base_commons:94:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -32,
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

**UPDATE** I check that browser memory increases a lot to a point that it crashes, it seems that the browser, scrapy or playwright do not close the open instances.

**UPDATE2** I post the code because I think that could be some routine bursting the memory. If anyone has any ideas it would be most welcome.

```
    import scrapy
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class LojaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'loja'
    start_urls = ['https://www.loja.com.br']    
    allowed_domains = ['loja.com.br']

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        # Obtém os links dos departamentos principais
        for link in response.xpath('//div[1][@class="nav-list-column"]//ul//li[@class="nav-item"]/a/@href'):
            yield response.follow( url=link.root, 
                errback =self.errback,
                meta = {
                'playwright' : True,
                'playwright_page_methods' : [PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div.css-1431dge-generic-carousel-generic-carousel--with-offset.e1w2odgr0')],
                }, callback=self.parse_sublinks)

    def parse_sublinks(self, response):
        # Acessa todos os sublinks e obtém os links para a grade de produtos.
        for link in response.css('div.swiper-slide'):
            url = link.css('a').attrib['href']

            yield response.follow( url=url,
                errback =self.errback, 
                meta = {
                'playwright' : True,
                # "playwright_include_page": True,
                'playwright_page_methods' : [PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div.css-agchm8-products--product-list.e1r1bq5m1')],
                }, callback = self.parse_products)
    
    async def parse_products(self, response):
        print('Link verificado: ', response.url )
        # Verifica se esta na grade de produtos para obter os itens.
        if response.css('div.css-agchm8-products--product-list.e1r1bq5m1'):
            for product in response.css('div.new-product-thumb'):
                yield {
                    'description': product.css('span.css-1eaoahv-ellipsis.enof0xo0::text').get(),
                    'price': product.css('span.css-gcz93e-price-tag__price.ehxrgxb3::text').get(),
                    'installment_price': product.css('span.css-4id40w-price-tag__content-wrapper.ehxrgxb0::text').get(),
                    'code': product.css('span.css-19qfvzb-new-product-thumb__product-code.ecqorlx1::text').get(),
                    'link': product.css('a').attrib['href']
                }

            current_page = response.css('div.css-bslizp-badge::text').get()
            next_link = response.css('i.glyph.glyph-arrow-right').get()
            next_page = int(current_page) + 1 if next_link else None
            
            if next_page:
                if int(current_page) > 1:
                    next_page_url = response.url[:-8] + '?page=' + str(next_page).rjust(2, '0')
 
                else:
                    next_page_url = response.url + '?page=' + str(next_page).rjust(2, '0')
      
                yield response.follow(next_page_url,
                    errback = self.errback, 
                    meta = {
                        'playwright' : True,
                        #"playwright_include_page": True,
                        'playwright_page_methods' : [PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'div.css-agchm8-products--product-list.e1r1bq5m1')],
                    },
                    callback=self.parse_products
                )

        # Verifica se esta na página direta do produto e obtem os itens.
        elif response.css('div.box-1'):
            print('Entrou no elif do div.box-1')
            yield {
                'description': response.css('h1.product-title.align-left.color-text product-description::text').get(),
                'price': response.css('span.css-rwb0cd-to-price__integer.e17u5sne7::text').get(),
                'installment_price': response.css('p.css-1b49m6w-text-text--bold-text-color--n400-text--kilo-heading--no-margin::text').get(),
                'code': response.css('div.badge.product-code.badge-product-code::text').get(),
            }
        else:
            print('Entrou no else para obter os links')
            # Caso não esteja na grade e na página do produto ele retorna para a função
            # parse_sublink com a url para poder captar os links do carrocel js.
            yield response.follow( url=response.url,
                errback =self.errback, 
                meta = {
                'playwright' : True,
                }, callback=self.parse_sublinks)

        # page = response.meta['playwright_page']
        # await page.close()

    async def errback(self, failure):
        page = failure.request.meta["playwright_page"]
        await page.close()
```

I searched a lot but dont find anything relevant considering I'm using scrapy(python) + playwright. Before had a error about overflow memory, but I solve with: export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192", I dont know if there's any connection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe dont necessary code because the problem occurs after one hour, possibly be a configuration in scrapy or playwright.

Comment: Which operating system are you using linux or wsl?

Comment: Linux, Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @Fabio have you figured it out?

Comment: @VaclovasRekašiusJr. I Solve with a palliative stopping the spider before 800 requests using CLOSESPIDER_PAGECOUNT = 800 in settings.py, also passing JOBDIR=crawls/name_of_spider when running, when stop i restart.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was because of an unclosed page instance, however, I see in your code page is closed.

Please make sure you did the following steps:

1. Close all playwright instances
2. Close all BrowserContext objects
3. Close all opened Page objects

Opened Playwright instance looks like this:

```py
playwright_instance = await async_playwright().start()
browser = await playwright_instance.firefox.launch(headless=headless, proxy=PROXIES[0])
context = await browser.new_context(java_script_enabled=True)
```

Here is my solution:

```py
await page.close()
await browser.close()
await playwright_instance.stop()
```